# Extracting a string between an "id_" and a ".html"

Tags: php

I want to extract the id from this Youku video:

http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTU2NzQyNzQ0.html?f=19275195&ev=3

The id is the random letter between the id_ and .html

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$input = 'http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTU2NzQyNzQ0.html?f=19275195&ev=3';
preg_match('~id_(.*?).html~', $input, $output);
echo $output[1];
```

## Output

```
XNTU2NzQyNzQ0
```

## Codepad

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
<?php
$varStr = 'http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTU2NzQyNzQ0.html?f=19275195&ev=3';
$filename = basename($varStr);
preg_match_all('/id_(.*)\.html/', $filename, $match);
echo $match[1][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of using named results in your REGEX, I would recommend doing something like this. Everyone else's work just fine, I've just added the named grouping as well as a non-greedy approach by ignoring periods

```
<?
$regex = "/\id_(?P<video_id>[^\.]*)\./";

if(preg_match($regex, "http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTU2NzQyNzQ0.html?f=19275195&ev=3", $matches)) {
        echo $matches['video_id'];
}
```